# Coefficient $x^{62}$ in $(x^3-\frac{1}{x^5})^{50}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient for $x^{62}$ in $(x^3-\frac{1}{x^5})^{50}$.

Binomial coefficients gives:
$$(x^3)^n (-\frac{1}{x^5})^{n-k}=x^{62}\\
3n-5(n-k)=62\Rightarrow 0=2n+5k-62\\
or\\\
3n+5(n-k)=62\Rightarrow 0=-8n+5k+62\\$$

When I put in the values, none satisfy the equations.

How can i solve this without trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\left(x^3-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)^{50}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}\binom{50}{k}(x^3)^k(-x^{-5})^{50-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{50}(-1)^k\binom{50}{k}x^{8k-250}$$
We want the coefficient for $x^{62}$, hence we solve $$8k-250=62\longrightarrow k=39$$
The term corresponding to $k=39$ is given by $$(-1)^{39}\binom{50}{39}x^{62}$$
So the coefficient for $x^{62}$ is $$(-1)^{39}\binom{50}{39}=-37353738800$$

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your equations: it should be simply
$$3k-5(50-k)=62\iff 8k=312.$$
Can you take it from there?